# Component is not rendering

Tags: javascript, reactjs

I'm working through the React 16 course on Udemy. We are using Codepen to create our first React apps in the course. Although the instructor is able to render the component in the video, I follow his code and it doesn't render. Here's the HTML, CSS, and JS code:

HTML:

```
<div class="person">
  <h1>Your name</h1>
  <p1>Manu</p1>
</div>
```

CSS:

```
.person {
  margin:10px;
  box-shadow:2px 2px #ccc;
  border: 1px solid #eee;
  padding: 20px;
  width: 200px;
  display: inline-block;
}
```

JavaScript:

```
function Person(){
  return(
    <div className="person">
      <h1>Your name</h1>
      <p1>Tristan</p1>
    </div>
  );
}

ReactDOM.render(<Person/>, document.querySelector('#p1'));
```

Comment: You have a misprint: `Persan` vs `Person`

Comment: Updated for person spelt incorrectly and class changed to className.

Comment: please share a public link to your solution on `Codepen`

Comment: Public solution: https://codepen.io/tristan-newman/pen/mGrqEp

Comment: Also see falinsky's comment below

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You have a misprint: `Persan` vs `Person`.

Also instead of `class` you should use `className` because `JSX` is just a `javascript` and keyword `class` is reserved.

Also instead of `p1` element I believe you should use either `p` or some custom component which will have a name started with a capital letter.

```js
function Person() {
  return (
    <div className="person">
      <h1>Your name</h1>
      <p>Tristan</p>
    </div>
  );
}

ReactDOM.render(<Person/>, document.querySelector('#p1'));
```

```css
.person{
  margin:10px;
  box-shadow:2px 2px #ccc;
  border: 1px solid #eee;
  padding: 20px;
  width: 200px;
  display: inline-block;
}
```

```html
<script crossorigin src="https://unpkg.com/react@16/umd/react.development.js"></script>
<script crossorigin src="https://unpkg.com/react-dom@16/umd/react-dom.development.js"></script>
<div id="p1"></div>
```

Comment: Thanks! It still isn't rendering after those 2 changes.

Comment: @TristanNewman also I've updated my solution with the information about using non-standard element `p1`

Comment: No. Just that it isn't rendering.

Comment: @TristanNewman so please share a public link to your solution on `Codepen`

Comment: Okay, your agustment to the HTML block, that imported the React and ReactDOM modules did the trick.

I don't understand why Codepen's modules didn't work, nor how to replicate your method incase it comes up again. 

Could you tell me the concept?

Comment: @TristanNewman the issue was in that you've loaded script containing `ReactDOM` before the one with `React` itself. see working example here: https://codepen.io/anon/pen/wEobGG  so you can just change the order of scripts you've enabled in `JS` section on `Codepen`

Comment: Yes. The Babel transpiler is enabled

Answer (score 0):

The issue is due to the typo `Persan` in the component declaration.
It should be

```
function Person(){
 return(
  <div className="person">
   <h1>Your name</h1>
   <p1>Tristan</p1>
  </div>
 );
}

ReactDOM.render(<Person/>, document.querySelector('#p1'));
```

Comment: you're not allowed to use `class` as a prop inside of `jsx`.